# Execute an SSRS Report from ASP.Net (unseen) supplying parameters, including printer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, printing, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new to SQL Server Reporting Services.  I can't seem to find the right walkthrough, but maybe I missed it.

I have an application that generates an order, and, once completed, I want it to generate a report that is sent directly to a printer based on the user generating the report.  Is there a good way to do this with SSRS?  I have the sample report deployed and I can run it from the Reports page.

Can anyone tell me if there is just not a good way to do this?  Years ago, I used Word with VB6 to automatically send reports successfully on a data sync with tablet inspection software for like 10 different inspectors, all organized the MS Access.  But that was not server-side.  Is it really not possible to shoot off a report with a couple parameters and have SQL Server Reporting Services send the report to a specified printer?

Comment: So no comments or anything?

Comment: Are you still working on this? I am doing something similar.

Comment: No we went in a different direction.